# Change Request Site - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: site-template, site

I need to develop a SharePoint 2010 application to control the Change Request, currently we are using a huge Excel sheet with more than 120 Fields.

I would like to break the Fields into smaller modules (i.e., Summary, Impact, Dependencies, Plan, Decision, Closure, Documents) and thought of creating Lists to store the details separately.

Would be using the SharePoint Tab feature provided here - http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx

Now, how do I ensure the referential integrity is maintained? means that, how do I maintain/pass the primary key value across the different tabs?

Is there any pre-build solution available for the same? Does it a bad idea to build such application on SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

All Easy Tabs does is convert existing web parts to be displayed in a tabbed format, if the script is removed it goes back to a normal view so your web parts have to work regardless if Easy Tabs is being used or not.

It sounds more like an architecture issue. If you are segmenting parts off to separate lists, they'll need to be associated with some sort of entry. So you'd probably do something like submitting part of the form that is the main entry, get it's list id, then submit the other points of data to their lists and associate them back to the parent via a lookup column to maintain the relationship.

Then you can build any sort of views you want because they are all tied to a master request.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, can you help me with any simple samples...